# Can variables be created then used on the LHS?

Tags: clips

I'm trying to learn CLIPS and this is a very basic question. I have facts for two people
(person (name "jim")(age 22))  and (person (name "sally")(age 32)) and I simply want a rule that will print out who is older,  or assert some fact like ( older (name "xxx")).
I was trying

```
(defrule compare "is jim older"
( person ( name "jim")(age ?jims_age))
( person ( name "sally")( age ?sallys_age))
(> ?jims_age ?sallys_age)
=>
(printout t "jim is older" crlf))
```

Which never activates.   So what is the right way to compare jim and sally's ages?
I can't find an easy example that does this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the test conditional element.

```
(defrule compare "is jim older"
  (person (name "jim") (age ?jims_age))
  (person (name "sally") (age ?sallys_age))
  (test (> ?jims_age ?sallys_age))
  =>
  (printout t "jim is older" crlf))
```

Your rule made generic:

```
(defrule compare "Compare two persons' age"
  (person (name ?name1) (age ?age1))
  (person (name ?name2) (age ?age2))
  (test (and (neq ?name1 ?name2) 
             (> ?age1 ?age2)))
  =>
  (printout t ?name1 " is older than " ?name2 crlf))
```

Explained in the `5.4.2 Test Conditional Element` chapter of the [Basic Programming Guide](http://clipsrules.sourceforge.net/documentation/v640/bpg.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, @noxdafox!  I hadn't gotten to that page yet.  I was sure there was a way to do this in one line!

Comment: Oh,  and thanks as well for noting (neq ?name1 ?name2) .  I'm sure I would have learned that the hard way if you hadn't mentioned it. :)